# How do I fix can't read property'role'of null?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem is whenever I type this

`` if(message.member.roles.cache.has(`something here`)) ``

The error comes **Cannot read property 'role' of null**

Any fixes?
I am new to coding . Please help.

Comment: role or roles ?

Comment: i really don't know , I tried both but same error also tried fetch then it has **can't read has undefined** something.

Comment: So that means your `message.member` does not have that property. Figure out what the properties of `member` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.member` might be null in your code. Check for the null/undefined case,

```
if(message.member && message.member.roles.cache.has(something here)) {
  // your code here

 }
```